# How do I combine two numpy arrays element wise in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have two numpy arrays:

```
A = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7])
B = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8])
```

and I want to get the following from combining the two:

```
C = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I'm able to get something close by using `zip`, but not quite what I'm looking for:

```
>>> zip(A, B)
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

How do I combine the two numpy arrays element wise?

---

I did a quick test of 50,000 elements in each array (100,000 combined elements).  Here are the results:

```
User Ma3x:      Time of execution: 0.0343832323429      Valid Array?:  True
User mishik:    Time of execution: 0.0439064509613      Valid Array?:  True
User Jaime:     Time of execution: 0.02767023558        Valid Array?:  True
```

<sup>Tested using Python 2.7, Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit, Intel Core i7 2720QM @2.2 Ghz Sandy Bridge, 8 GB Mem</sup>

Comment: Here's [a link to the code](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116/conversation/testing-the-element-wise-array-combine) that I used to test this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`np.insert`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html):

```
>>> A = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7])
>>> B = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8])
>>> np.insert(B, np.arange(len(A)), A)
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Comment: for a `N-D array` you should also pass the `axis` parameter to indicate along which axis you want to insert the new array...

Answer (score 6):

You can also use slices :

```
C = np.empty((A.shape[0]*2), dtype=A.dtype)
C[0::2] = A
C[1::2] = B
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A=np.array([1,3,5,7])
>>> B=np.array([2,4,6,8])
>>> C=np.dstack([A,B])
>>> D=C.reshape((1,8))[0]
>>> D
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Comment: A couple of variations on this: `np.dstack([A,B]).flatten()`, and `np.array([A,B]).T.flatten()`

Comment: Your answer times at 267 us, compared to 8.59 ms for the Jamie insert method (a 300x speedup).

Answer (score 3):

Some answers suggested sorting, but since you want to combine them element-wise sorting won't achieve the same result.

Here is one way to do it

```
C = []
for elem in zip(A, B):
    C.extend(elem)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
C = sorted(A.tolist() + B.tolist())
```

1. `A.tolist()` will yield `[1, 3, 5, 7]`
2. `B.tolist()` will yield `[2, 4, 6, 8]`
3. `A.tolist() + B.tolist()` - `[1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8]`
4. `sorted(...)` - `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

Without sorting:

```
C = [y for x in zip(A, B) for y in x]
```

Comment: I don't want the elements to be sorted, as these are actually data samples that aren't in order of value. Your second option was used in my testing.

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
A = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7])
B = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8])
```

You can use:

```
np.array([A, B]).transpose().flatten().tolist()
```

And it works with any number of arrays as well.